# Why do I get the same number every time I dequeue my queue?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm supposed to enqueue some integers into a queue and then calculate the sum and average...

I believe I am enqueueing my data in correctly, but when I dequeue I seem to get the last integer I enqueued.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main(void)
{
  int intgr;
  int avg = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  int* dataPtr;
  QUEUE* queue;
  queue = createQueue();

  printf("Enter 5 integers to calc sum and average:\n\n");

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    intgr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &intgr);
    dataPtr = &intgr;
    enqueue(queue, dataPtr);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    dequeue(queue, (void*)&dataPtr);
    printf("%d", *dataPtr);
    sum += *dataPtr;
  }

  printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
  printf("Avg: %d\n", sum/5);

  return 0;
}
```

My dequeue operation:

```
bool dequeue(QUEUE* queue, void** itemPtr)
{
  //Local Definitions
  QUEUE_NODE* deleteLoc;

  //Statements
  if(!queue->count)
    return false;

  *itemPtr = queue->front->dataPtr;
  deleteLoc = queue->front;
  if(queue->count == 1 )
    // Delete only item in queue
    queue->rear = queue->front = NULL;
  else
    queue->front = queue->front->next;
  (queue->count)--;
  free(deleteLoc);

  return true;
} // dequeue
```

Comment: Because the data item address you're loading in your queue for every item pushed is that of the *same* automatic variable in `main()`, namely `intgr`. Debug your program and walk your queue chain, you'll see all the data pointers point to the **same** address. Related, this makes no sense at all: `intgr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));`. if that doesn't flag a compiler warning, nothing will. It is (a) wrong, and (b) a memory leak, since you obliterate the allocation address the moment you perform your `scanf`.

Comment: I am getting this warning when I compile: ` warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] intgr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` but I get the same result even if I remove this line out of my code.

Comment: `int intgr;` is not a pointer. It is integer storage, hence the warning.

Comment: See second part of my comment.

Comment: Thanks, I see how its always pointing back to that same address. I thought malloc would re-allocate a different memory address every time the loop runs. It was just a guess... I'm new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup for your data pointer is not correct. This is completely wrong:

```
intgr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Not only should that flag a giant warning due to improper conversion, there is no guarantee it will even work. Further, the value in `intgr` is later overwritten with:

```
scanf("%d", &intgr);
```

so you leaked memory anyway, even if by some chance `int` on your platform is large enough to hold `void*`.

What you want to do is this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0;
    QUEUE* queue = createQueue();

    printf("Enter 5 integers to calc sum and average:\n\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int value;
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", &value);

        int *dataPtr = malloc(sizeof *dataPtr);
        *dataPtr = value;
        enqueue(queue, dataPtr);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        void *vptr = NULL;
        dequeue(queue, &vptr);
        if (vptr)
        {
            int *dataPtr = vptr;
            printf("%d", *dataPtr);
            sum += *dataPtr;
        }
        free(vptr);
    }

    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    printf("Avg: %d\n", sum/5);

    return 0;
}
```

And obviously, there should be a LOT more error checking, cleanup, etc. but I'm leaving that to you.

You have another issue, which is covered in a multitude of questions already. `void*` is the typeless generic pointer type in C. `void**` is *not* some pointer-to-pointer generic. The latter is a very specific type (a pointer to a pointer-to-void). As such, your cast is improper. It has been addressed in the code above, and you should look at it closely.

Comment: what do you mean by 'leaked memory'?

Comment: @TheXales It means you were effectively throwing away the prior result of `malloc` when you overwrite `intgr` with the integer you read from `scanf`. Once that address is gone, there is no way to recover it, therefore no way to `free` it, therefore it is indeed "leaked". The code I posted does not do that, and further, actually cleans up the dynamic allocations it produced.

Comment: free should be inside the `if`

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks!

Comment: @stark it doesn't matter. its a no-op if `vptr` is NULL. Either location works.